# handle mousedrag() for two different game objects individually in 2D environment

Tags: unity, 2d, monodevelop

I am developing a pong game for android mobiles having 2 slider and want to assign movement of  individual slider corresponding to its current position

[image]

I tried some code for the movement of these sliders using OnMouseDrag();

```
void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, mousePos.y);

    }
```

I got the movement for the sliders but problem is that, I can only slide one slider at a time
But I need to move both the sliders at the same time using both hands because this game is getting developed for android mobiles environment.

please Help....

Comment: Maybe mouse isn't the best solution for android mobiles. Have you tried using Input.touches?

Comment: no don't have proper idea to use Input.touches

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this, is to divide your screen in 2 and check to see if someone is holding down a finger in that area.  An easy way to do this, is to add two large Box Colliders on each side of your game scene, which will serve as a hit detection for Touches.

Check if the Collider is pressed, and then simulate the corresponding paddle with that touch.

This is just some untested sample code you can play around with, can be greatly improved on:

```
public BoxCollider2D Paddle1Collider;
public BoxCollider2D Paddle2Collider;


void Update()
{

    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {

        RaycastHit2D[] hits; 
        Vector2 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touch.position);
        hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll (pos, new Vector2 (0, 0), 0.01f);

        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++) {
            if (hits [i].collider == Paddle1Collider) {
                Paddle1.Move(pos);
            }
            else if (hits [i].collider == Paddle2Collider) {
                Paddle2.Move(pos);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: not able to divide the screen in to two parts using collider...any help please

Comment: @SantoshYadav Can you give me more information as to why you cannot do this?

Comment: actually i am new for 2D game development and don't know how to add an empty collider means without any game object.

Comment: Create a blank gameObject and add a collider to it ;)

Comment: actually i did that but it disturbing the position of both sliders

Comment: If you set the new colliders to Triggers, it will not collide with your existing physics objects.  Alternatively, you can assign your colliders to a layer, and then edit the physics2d properties of your project, so that those two layers do not collide with each other.

Comment: i have added colliders on both sides but not sure where to assign script for the movement do i need to assign it on sliders or on both box colliders